# Reorder rows in a dataframe based on column in another dataframe but with non-unique values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.

The first dataframe, df1, has 1246 rows and looks like this:

```
                 gene1         gene2          gene3
AAAB.P1           1.23          2.28          -2.85
AABC.P1           4.06         -0.59          -2.42
ABCD.P1           3.26          2.19          -3.01
ABCD.R1           1.23          0.15          -2.30
DBCA.P1           1.67         -0.51          -3.24
```

The second dataframe, df2, also has 1246 rows and looks like this:

```
    id      primary_diagnosis
1   ABCD    carcinoma
2   ABCD    carcinoma
3   AAAB    AS
4   DBCA    carcinoma
5   EFGH    other
6   LMNO    AS
```

I need to rearrange the second df so that it is in the same order as the first df, based on the id column. I tried to use

```
df2<-df2[order(match(df2$id, substr(rownames(df1), 1, 4))), ]
```

But it only gave me 21 rows that were in the correct position. I think the problem is that df2 contains some duplicates. For example, ABCD has both ABCD.P1 and ABCD.R1 in df1 but only one entry in df2. It doesn't matter which order they go in because both P1 and R1 will match up with carcinoma. How can I reorder df2 to match whatever order df1 is already in?

Comment: You may have to order by `primary_diagnosis` and then by the `match` with `id`

Comment: does `df2[rank(rownames(df1), ties.method = "random"), ]` work for you?

Comment: @akrun hmm it looks like that gave me the same result, with only 21 of the rows being in the right order

Comment: @CFD your solution worked! If you make it an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `df2[rank(rownames(df1), ties.method = "random"), ]`.

The `ties.method = "random"` argument ensures that each rank is unique in the event that there are ties.

Answer (score 1):

We could use simple `arrange` in this way:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  arrange(id, df1$id)
```

```
    id primary_diagnosis
3 AAAB                AS
1 ABCD         carcinoma
2 ABCD         carcinoma
4 DBCA         carcinoma
5 EFGH             other
6 LMNO                AS
```

```
#df1
df1 <- structure(list(gene1 = c(1.23, 4.06, 3.26, 1.23, 1.67), gene2 = c(2.28, 
-0.59, 2.19, 0.15, -0.51), gene3 = c(-2.85, -2.42, -3.01, -2.3, 
-3.24)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("AAAB.P1", "AABC.P1", 
"ABCD.P1", "ABCD.R1", "DBCA.P1"))

#df2
df2 <- structure(list(id = c("ABCD", "ABCD", "AAAB", "DBCA", "EFGH", 
"LMNO"), primary_diagnosis = c("carcinoma", "carcinoma", "AS", 
"carcinoma", "other", "AS")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "id gene1 gene2 gene3
AAAB.P1 1.23 2.28 -2.85
AABC.P1 4.06 -0.59 -2.42
ABCD.P1 3.26 2.19 -3.01
ABCD.R1 1.23 0.15 -2.30
DBCA.P1 1.67 -0.51 -3.24", sep=" ", header=TRUE)
rownames(df1) <- df1$id
df1 <- df1[,-1]


df2 <- read.table(text="id primary_diagnosis
ABCD carcinoma
ABCD carcinoma
AAAB AS
DBCA carcinoma
EFGH other
LMNO AS", sep=" ", header=TRUE)


df2[match(substr(rownames(df1), 1, 4), df2$id), ]
#>       id primary_diagnosis
#> 3   AAAB                AS
#> NA  <NA>              <NA>
#> 1   ABCD         carcinoma
#> 1.1 ABCD         carcinoma
#> 4   DBCA         carcinoma
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure why but that just replaces everything with NA for me

Comment: It will replace the values for `id` that don't have corresponding values in `rownames(df1`)` with `NA`, like it did for the values corresponding to the second row of `df1`where the first part of the  row name is `AABC`, which doesn't have a corresponding entry in `df2$id`.